# Can I assume my data is following poisson distribution here?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, inference, poisson-distribution

I am working on a data of call center , it is given that *between the same time period everyday the number of calls are same and there is no dependency between the calls*.

Can I apply poisson distribution to such data on number of calls between some specific time without checking anything else ?
Or should this have to have ***Variance = Mean*** then only I can apply ?

I am new to this all , can anyone give some suggestion on this part.

Answer (score 0):

Poisson distributions assume there are no simultaneous/concurrent events. To an extent, it depends on your unit of time.

$$P(k{\text{ events in interval}})=e^{-\lambda }{\frac {\lambda ^{k}}{k!}}$$

If busy enough call centers, there is probably >1 calls / day. Therefore, you can model it as poisson dist with unit of time as 30 minutes or something like that.